# Find the sum of all coefficients in expansion of $(x^2+2x)^{20}$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of all coefficients in expansion of $(x^2+2x)^{20}$.

Is there a specific method or formula for this?

Comment: Yes, there is. Do you know another way to describe the sum of the coefficients of a polynomial $P(x)$?

Comment: Nice hint, @Daniel! Let's hope no one spoils it. Satvik - you can figure it out!

Comment: f(1) is the sum..

Comment: Compare the form of the binomial expansion with the sum of the coefficients. Is there an $x$ for which they agree? (You could also try with a smaller exponent and look for a pattern.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the coefficients of a polynomial is just the value that such polynomial takes in $1$, hence:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}[x^n](x^2+2x)^{20} = (1+2)^{20} = 3^{20}.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?